# Monitor that I can control its brightness from keyboards/OS settings section

Tags: keyboard, display

I am stuck with a 2008 Apple Cinema Display because every monitor I try, I can not control its brightness from the keyboard and that's a must for me.

I am unsure what I should be searching for to get such monitor. I change the brightness multiple times per hour so I can't simply reach to the screen to make the adjustments. I absolutely need to control it via keyboard.

What are some of the available monitors that allows such functionality and why it's possible with them and not the others?

Comment: Did you see this [How can I adjust brightness of 3rd Party external monitor on iMac, Macbook or Mac Pro via keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314090/how-can-i-adjust-brightness-of-3rd-party-external-monitor-on-imac-macbook-or-ma?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your external monitor supports [DDC/CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel#DDC/CI). If so, you can use [this](https://github.com/fnesveda/ExternalDisplayBrightness/) app to adjust the brightness using your keyboard.