# Do any third-party monitors natively support brightness keys?

Tags: macos, display

**TL; DR**: Apple monitors (in laptops, desktops, and external) support using the F1/F2 keys for brightness control. Do any third party monitors support this functionality *natively*?

**Context**: I have a [Dell P2721Q](https://www.dell.com/il/en/p/dell-p2721q-monitor/pd) monitor attached to an M2 MacBook Pro (and an Intel MBP prior to that). I seem to recall that my brightness keys worked perfectly with it, out of the box. (*Important*: Perhaps this is completely incorrect; I am honestly not 100% sure, since I also use an Apple Studio Display in another setup, where it does work, and I might only be thinking of that.)

Yesterday, the monitor stopped accepting my laptop's video. After quite a long set of attempts — changing cables, rebooting the laptop, changing various monitor configurations, it still didn't work, until I finally tried the obvious thing: actually unplugging the monitor from the wall (not just turning it off by the switch). And it worked! I then got spooked and found that there was a firmware update online, which I applied, with no obvious changes. (*This whole paragraph might be a red herring*...)

However, after this I noticed that I couldn't change the brightness via the keyboard, or the Displays panel of “System Settings” (but see above — perhaps I never could!). I have checked that DDC/CI is enabled, and certainly all of the other settings (various power and USB settings) seem as before, but F1/F2 still don't seem to work (I can set the brightness etc just fine using the monitor hardware controls).

I am aware of, and have tried, [MonitorControl](https://github.com/MonitorControl/MonitorControl), [Lunar](https://lunar.fyi) and other similar software, and of [similar questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/314090/how-can-i-adjust-brightness-of-3rd-party-external-monitor-on-imac-macbook-or-ma) here.

So:

- Was I hallucinating that it ever worked?
- If not, any idea what might have changed?
- Are there any monitors that do support this?

Comment: It has never worked for me with a non-Apple branded monitor.

Comment: Potential Dupe:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/336750/119271  It’s about volume, but ultimately it’s the same issue, Mac computers cannot control these devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t natively control monitor brightness, power state (on/off) or volume because macOS doesn’t support the [CEC (Consume Electronics Control) protocol](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336751/119271).

There is a potential workaround called [MonitorControl](https://github.com/MonitorControl/MonitorControl) (FOSS) that will utilize the on-screen display controls of your monitor.  There seems to be an option to synchronize brightness or utilize alternate keys to control brightness.  It’s available as a download (DMG) from GitHub or via [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/monitorcontrol)

Comment: MonitorControl made F1/F2 keys working for me with my external Dell monitor 

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does seem like I *was* hallucinating: non-Apple external monitors do not seem to support the brightness keys (which is annoying; why not?).

[Here's a post on the Dell product forums](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/P2721Q-native-support-for-macOS-brightness-keys/m-p/8397263/highlight/true#M147436) that discusses their monitors in general.

Comment: I think the LG UltraFine models that Apple sold had native brightness control.